# Cannot change active tab in Swing, "Non static method cannot be referenced"

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtabbedpane

I'm currently having an issue with Swing, where I am trying to get a button from Tab 1, once clicked on, to go to tab 2. The two blocks of code that are at work here, as far as I know, are as follows:

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane;
// End of variables declaration                   

private void addTabs() {
    this.jTabbedPane.add("Home page", new Home());
    this.jTabbedPane.add("Nieuwe Gebruiker", new UserNew());
    this.jTabbedPane.add("Terugkerende gebruiker", new UserReturning());
    this.jTabbedPane.add("Ingelogde gebruiker", new UserReturning());
    this.jTabbedPane.add("Administrator", new Admin());
}

public void setTab(String tabName) {
    this.jTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(jTabbedPane.indexOfTab(tabName));
}
```

And:

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO Go to user logged in page
    FullHouse.setTab("UserLoggedIn");
}
```

However, the latter piece of code is giving an error on calling the setTab method:

```
non-static method setTab(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I have tried making the setTab method static, but then Netbeans complains about the jTabbedPane not being static. I am not able to make the jTabbedPane static, as Netbeans won't allow me to edit the code in this manner.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `FullHouse` a concrete instance of that class? If it's not a concrete instance (variable) and you are trying to call `setTab(...)` method directly on the class name, then you have the reason why you are getting that message.

Comment: Try with `FullHouse.this.setTab("UserLoggedIn");`

Comment: I didn't create an instance of FullHouse. It's the main JFrame which contains the jTabbedPane which contains the JPanels. At least, that's how I get it. Everything was standard created by Netbeans with the Design option they have.

@GuillaumePolet That doesn't work, the second code block is inside a seperate class, which is one of the JPanels that the jTabbedPane is supposed to display

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance of FullHouse that you can call setTab on.
In other words, the compiler is asking, WHICH FullHouse do you want to call setTab on? You hopefully instantiated it somewhere.

Can't give more specifics without more details from your first code block.

Comment: Not sure what your MouseListener is registered on, but you might also try using `((Something) evt.getSource()).possiblySomethingElse().setTab("UserLoggedIn")`

Again, not enough code given to provide more specifics.